# Does google drive keep revisions forever?

Tags: version-control, google-drive-api, version, revision

I am trying to build my app and use google drive to store data. I would like to have complete history of file changes. Is that possible with google drive through revisions?

UPD: If it matters, I am plan to store compact JSON data. Very unlikely to be more than 1MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation, it is possible to track all the file changes; but in order to keep all the revisions, you need use the `keepRevisionForever` parameter. See [Manage Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions).

> Google Drive automatically purges (or "prunes") revisions in order to optimize disk usage. To prevent this from happening, you can set the boolean flag `keepRevisionForever` to `true` to mark revisions that you don't want Drive to purge.

You can also check the [`Revisions`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions) resource which has `list`, `get`, `delete` and `update` functions.